# Multiple vs single field capture for phone number form input

Tags: forms, input, responsive

Working on a form dealing with phone numbers, I've seen two methods to capture user input .

In past practices example 2 (image below) has proved effective in controlling phone number lengths on forms.

However with responsive in mind it would seem example 1 is considered a more popular pattern on forms. I've researched both patterns with the findings below.

[image: Phone Number Input Patterns on Form]

**Example 1**

*Pros*

- 1 input = less taps on mobile device
- 1 input = less coding

*Cons*

- could be difficult to control phone number format (1-555-555-5555, +22444455555, and etc)

**Example 2**

*Pros*

- easier to control phone format
- reduced user error

*Cons*

- 3 inputs = more taps on mobile device
- more inputs = more coding

Both inputs have pros and cons and I'm not such which method would provide the best user experience for responsive environments. Can anyone share some insight or provide a better way to use phone number inputs?

Comment: Example 2 is horrible for non-US numbers.

Comment: Sample 2 only covers phone numbers of a certain structure, which the user must know. There’s a lot of variety internationally. It also doesn’t work well with copy-paste.

Comment: related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/17480/54280

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/friendly-format-for-phone-numbers

Comment: The related topics are insightful and really eye-opening to the various types of phone formats. Kind of makes example 2 not look like a good choice IF you are supporting internal numbers. However it it's based say in the United States it could work. I guess it depends on the audience the form is for in the end.

Comment: It should also be noted that using a single field of `type="tel"` is probably the best UX for mobiles - when focused, a numpad is shown instead of the usual keyboard

Comment: To short to be an answer, but important to note: Many people when faced with (2) will become irritated, possibly to the point of closing the website then and there instead of continuing.  Especially on a phone, every keypress costs substantial time and effort (when compared to the pittance of free time the average person has in a day).  Looking up after typing 10 numbers and seeing the last 7 were ignored is demotivating to say the least.  It leaves users feeling like you don't respect their time or convenience.  Ask yourself this: what advantage does (2) convey *to the user*?

Comment: For the second approach, why not auto-tab?  Ex: for the first textbox user types in 3 characters. When user types in the fourth character, automatically focus on the next textbox.

Comment: @Pathachiever11 Even for the first field, you would need to look up the international prefix to find the lenght of the code. Oh, and `+` means the same as `00` at the start, but has different lenght.

Comment: @UweKeim Also US numbers, if you have an extension

Comment: @Izkata: I should of included an ext. input but you're right example 2 wouldn't work well for them.

Comment: Actually... how would you include an extension inside a single input? I've only seen a separate input used for extensions. Can anyone provide a pattern/article displaying a single input including the extension?

Comment: @CourtneyJordan Aren't extensions usually on business cards with a pound sign?  So something like: `15551234567 #9876` (Edit - Google Image Search seems to indicate there is no standard.  So it might be worthwhile to store both the original and stripped-down version)

Answer (score 36):

When a person dials an actual phone number with their phone, do they type `1-555-555-555` or do they type `15555555555`?

The only reason for forcing a fixed format is because your back-end can't determine the format it needs. Which is an implementation problem and you're forcing the lack of technical nous onto the end user. That's like saying *"we aren't capable of parsing a phonenumber into a format that we want, so we're going to ask you to type in it the format we want"*.

Just like with credit card numbers - we are mostly no longer expected to type `1111`-`1111`-`1111`-`1111` in 4 separate fields and pick `visa` from a dropdown because there is already enough information in the credit card string itself to know the type of card, and we can easily split a single number `1111111111111111` into 4 'chunks' if that's how we need it in the back end.

You should try to set up some kind of intelligence in the logic itself. For instance if you know the country the person is from then you will know the format of the phone number, and if you know it's a mobile phone and not a landline then that's another clue for you to use. Then just give the user a single field and let them type in a number however they like.

Heck, some people will want to use a single field and type `+44 (020) 444 4444` in there themselves. But you should be able to strip out all the unnecessary characters and spaces programatically and store it as a single field.

Let the programming do the grunt work, not the user.

Comment: I sadly have fallen victim to typing in the 1 when dialing a phone number (force of habit). Overall i've seen various ways people input phone numbers from using the 1 to dialing the seven numbers. I've actually watched my mother (not technical savvy in any shape or form) type in the () around the area code which made the form she was inputing data fail of course it didn't help there was no error message instructing her not to use them, lol.

Comment: Yeah, people don't read hints / error messages really. Just let them type whatever they want and then strip out all the irrelevant characters afterwards. Saves all that bother.

Comment: Surely a UK phone number is written as one of the following: `+44 (0)20 444 4444`, `+44 20 444 4444`, or `(020) 444 4444`. Your example seems to be a hybrid.

Comment: @TRiG Some people may know about stripping the preceeding `0` off, some wouldn't. But that's the point - as the developer we would be able to *programatically* tell that the `0` is superfluous and can therefore be removed.

Comment: Just curious is there a way you can detect a number format by location within your browser? I know on mobile devices as you type the number it formats automatically but never seen it on the desktop level.

Comment: “… () around the area code which made the form she was inputing data fail of course” There’s no reason whatsoever for ‘of course’ here. It was‘t your mother’s fault. Anyway, in modern browsers, `<input type=tel>` should do much of the magic.

Comment: Upvote for Jon for getting to the heart of the matter. Put the burden on the application to decipher the format, not the user. Courtney, this UX technique is called "Forgiving Format". And leads to better UX on all sorts of inputs.

Comment: @Crissov you misread my reply. "of course it didn't help there was no error message instructing her not to use them" It wasn't my mothers fault...I know that. There was no error message telling her otherwise as stated.

Comment: @TRiG In the UK (in my experience) it tends to be `01234 456 789`, `01234 456789`, `+44 (0)1234 456 789` or finally `+44 (0)1234 456789`. Although you do get the end bit as `45 67 89` sometimes - usually as part of an advert where repeating pairs of numbers are easier to remember, the four above seem most common. I don't think I've ever seen it split the way you or the OP have written it. There is a different varient for `0800` numbers too, they tend to be `0800 1234 567` unless they are short in which case they lose one from the first grouping of four.

Comment: On the first part of this answer, it used to be the `1` prefix was required, so I thought all phones still accept `15555555555`

Comment: In the case of the credit card number, "chunking" the input can be helpful for the user trying to input a long string of digits correctly.

Comment: I think "Let the programming do the grunt work, not the user." might be my new favourite quote.

Answer (score 8):

A single input field is always easiest for the user — whether it's for a phone number, first and last name, social security number, or any other value that you may think of as being divided into "parts". Luke Wroblewski has written [many](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?832) [articles](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1667) about this with plenty of data to back it up.

Design your page for the user, not the database. If you absolutely need to break up a phone number into separate pieces (international prefix, area code, exchange, post code) before storing it, then make an attempt to do so but verify it with the user.

For example, if the user types in `5551234567` you could unobtrusively prompt them to confirm that `(555) 123-4567` is correct. Be sure to give them a way to fix it along with a way to clarify why your guess was wrong (e.g. it may not be a U.S. phone number, so let them specify their country).

Be liberal with what you accept — allow the user to use a plus sign for an international prefix (and use that in your algorithm!) as well as any other punctuation they feel is necessary. Everyone has their own style of formatting.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you keep one input field, but use a mask for the text:
[image]

-You can use Placeholder attribute from HTML5 (If you are working in a web App) for showing a example number.

Comment: I had thought about using a mask but there are issues dealing with screen readers that can be seen in this video. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9rGmqNcHo-mRGpMS0xQbzVzeGM/edit it's not pretty...

Answer (score 4):

My guiding principles for this are as follows, vis-à-vis users:

1. Show them what you expect
2. Take whatever they give you
3. Show them what you’re taking

The best way to accomplish all three with HTML5 and jQuery is to borrow [this plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo).

[image]

I’ve added `type="tel"` mainly to give mobile users a keypad instead of a keyboard, and `placeholder="(999) 999-9999"` as a better way of displaying the expected format. When you leave out `placeholder`, or when focus is placed in this field, the user will see this:

[image]

At this point, they can type or paste in whatever numbers they want and see them nicely filled in. If they try to type or paste in any other characters, they simply get ignored. The end result is a nice looking number that should be friendly and recognizable to the user and the system.

If you want to cover international possibilities, ask for the user’s country first and then use form logic to display a field you’ve customized for that country (adjust regular expressions/definitions in jQuery).

Comment: I always wondered whether ignoring non-numeric characters is always the best way. You could, for instance, transform letters A|B|C → 2, D|E|F → 3, G|H|I → 4, J|K|L → 5, M|N|O → 6, P|Q|R|S → 7, T|U|V → 8, W|X|Y|Z → 9.

Comment: @Crissov I think any benefit to individual users who want to enter their phone numbers with letters (and surely they should be able to enter the numbers) would be outweighed in the aggregate by confusion of users who are entering letters by accident or because they didn’t understand the field.

Comment: You don't need a table.

Comment: @Crissov That would be real awkward. That is old-school conventional phone semantics. They have no place on a web-site. To make matters worse: Those keys aren't as standardized as you think. Especially 6 and higher can be mapped differently. Eg. 6:PQR, 7:STU, 8: VWX, 9:YZ. Some variants include the "0" as well.

Answer (score 3):

From my testing, I have learned that you NEVER, EVER, use a single empty field to represent a phone number (or credit card, or any other multi-part field). I've watched users often make mistakes when typing one long number, then not being able to find the mistake they made. With a multi-part field, they pinpointed the mistake easier ("oh, the first number of the 2nd field is wrong!"). Users are also simply used to typing in multi-part numbers as... multi-part numbers. Your phone service provider doesn't tell you your number is 10982859205, they tell you your number is 1 (098) 285-9205. When a person tells their number to another person, they don't speak it all as one number; they break it up just as it is written. When you read a number off a credit card, it's not written as one giant number; it's written as chunks of 4 numbers. Users are used to it, and if you follow JonW's answer, it WILL test badly.

There are already lots of answers that discuss input masks, which is probably the best/easiest solution, but I have also seen well-coded multi-field solutions test well. By "well-coded", I mean fields which will correctly copy and paste values, automatically jump to the next field when typing (removing the need to tap on mobile devices), and automatically reverse-jump when the user hits backspace. Multi-field solutions work, but your point about "more inputs = more coding" is right on the money.

Comment: Welcome to UX Exchange. Please refine your answer to include specific examples of your research. Also please focus on your answer, there is no need to call out another user. If you have a question or comment for another users answer please do so in the comment area for the other users answer. Thank you.

Comment: Many numbers (and alphanumeric identifiers) have conventional arrangements with separators, the most popular probably being the thousands separator (`,`, `.`, `’` or whitespace), which make long strings easier to read (also popular: `-`, `:`, `(`…`)` etc.). Some people will also input these, or hit tab instead. Still, in their mind it is a single number (or ID), not several fields, although some may have special semantics (e.g. area code), but often nobody knows that, e.g. the issuer ID in a credit card number spans the 2nd to 6th of 16 digits arbitrarily arranged in 4 equal chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Go with Example 1. One field for the phone number.

Do some quick client side regex on the number the user entered, to account for any egregious errors to save an unecessary call to your server for 800 digit entries or garbled text.

Ultimately, you are validating the web form data on the server and sanitizing it before dropping it into your database.

Comment: If you're sanitizing it for database input you may want to do all of the validation on the server so it's the same code. (Just use ajax to pass the value and get the validation result.) Then you avoid having separate client and server validations which can become out of sync and may not be 100% identical due to programming language differences. You wouldn't want a JS validation to give a thumbs up only to have the database reject it because the JS missed some edge case.

Comment: I disagree. I meant a quick validation. As in: don't allow 800 digits or alpha characters. Saves a call to your server.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've specified that you will only be using this form for a US audience, I don't really see a problem with guiding the user towards using a particular format.  However, using multiple text fields might not be the best way to go about that.  Let's study some existing websites as examples:

[image: Multiple input fields]

[Papa John's Pizza](https://order.papajohns.com/secure/register.html) uses multiple fields for their account creation.  As the user types, it automatically switches to the next field which is helpful because the user doesn't have to click or tab multiple times, but it can be confusing if the user isn't expecting it.  If the user mistypes, it's not easy to go back to another section and correct it.

[image: Single field with validation]

[Jimmy John's](https://online.jimmyjohns.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=jimmy%20johns&utm_content=37437283910&utm_campaign=JJ%20Brands%20Group%2010%20-%20Enhanced#/register/accountinfo) uses a single field with validation to ensure the user types in a real phone number.  This ensures that the user inputs the desired format, but the coding to make this work can be difficult.  Plus, if an error occurs, it may be difficult for the user to find it.

[image: Single field with text mask]

[Pizza Hut](https://order.pizzahut.com/site/registration) uses a single field with a text mask.  This allows a user to input all the numbers at once while specifying the format.  It prevents the user from typing too much or too little into the field and it's easy to figure out where errors occurred.  I like it.  (It's worth noting that Domino's uses the same type of input field, though they likely just copied each other.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for option 1 due to the ease of use from purely a responsive view point and like said earlier, if you plan to use the area code etc to some how collate your data and categorizes phone numbers.

The last thing you would want is that number in separate inputs stacking on mobile or device although it wouldn't be a complete disaster again the con of having too many clicks would come into play with less fluidity for the end user...

Again accounting for parentheses and plus signs should also figure, lets not discriminate :)

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1. + input mask

An input mask ([this type, not a password field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/58316/54280)) allows the user to type in their number in one go (as if they were dialing for example), yet have the number formatted before it is submitted.
This reduces the physical effort (navigating to the next input) and the mental effort (splitting up the number and context switching to the task of navigating to the next input - something outside the usual pattern of dialing a phone; the general use case)
See [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/17511/54280)

It is flexible in that the spaces in a format such as `01234 456 789` can be typed, or left out by the user.

If it is required that the international extension is also input, either:

- Make it clear on the form, so the user will input the correct number
  (e.g. `+nn nnnn nnn nnn` - have the + already there in the input
  mask
  or even `+nn (n)nnnn nnn nnn`)
- Have a seperate county - code field, so they can still input their 'local' number. As something that is usually not included in their number, having it as a seperate entity is not user-unfriendly.

Answer (score -1):

One form field, such as the one presented in option one, is a better experience. You could make the input flexible by allowing the user to enter their phone number in whatever format they wish and using logic to clean it up for the database. For example, a user could enter 123-456-7890, (123) 456-7890, 123.456.7890, etc and they would all be valid.

Comment: This is just re-iterating my own answer. Please don't duplicate other answers unless you have something new or can expand / enhance such posts. Otherwise we'll just get people saying exactly the same thing in 100s of different ways.