# What is the term for a numeric input field of a specific format?

Tags: interface, terminology, input-fields, input, numbers

There are new HTML5 input types being defined for commonly used numeric input types such as date, time, telephone number, etc. These terms refer to a specific input format based on the type of numeric data that needs to be captured and displayed.

I was wondering if there is a more generic term used for numeric input that is required in a specific format (but not any particular format), since the term 'specific format numeric input' is probably not commonly used. This would indicate that the input field is not a free text input that is then validated, but the format of the input itself would create some constraints in the type of numeric data that can be entered. An example of this would be credit card details with digits separated the same way as it is displayed on the credit card.

The only thing that comes to mind is a 'fixed' or 'formatted' numeric input field. Any other suggestions?

**Free text format**

**Fixed input format**
[image: Free numeric input field]
[image]

This should not be a 'technical' sounding term since it is also intended for UX specification for designers and other UX people, so I prefer not to use a developer term but something everyone can understand. Also, the term should reflect the fact that it is not a free text looking field, but something that already indicates to the user that it has a specific input format.

Comment: I think it's called a mask.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky Is that just a technical term, or is there a more 'user friendly' way of describing it?

Comment: It's pretty technical, I wouldn't try to use it with the general public.

Comment: please don't try to change anything a user types in ever -- http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/74019/58111 -- you can give feedback to the user when their input doesn't make any sense but don't change it for them because it causes frustration and friction.

Comment: @DaveAlger I think it is a balance of the input field format (e.g. letting the user know what format the input should be in), providing sensible instructions or help text where required, and some intelligent processing of user input that will solve the problem. I agree that it is not generally advisable to change what the user types in, so we should try as much as we can to let them know through the interface design or other interactions to avoid this issue.

Comment: In general, this doesn't have to be numeric. The payment source could be an email address or a URL for instance. I think a correct term could be **pattern** or **format**.

Comment: @DaveAlger, I'm unable to find much re input masks increasing user  frustration. I see many articles citing their benefit -- [LukeW](http://goo.gl/yNzOvb), [Smashing](http://goo.gl/pKX1V) -- of _prevening_ users from entering bad data, but haven't been able to find much on the negative impact. If you have any resources on-hand, I'd love to take a look. I'm implementing these on one of my apps and would like to know if I've made a poor decision. But, it seems that the frustration from bad data being entered might outweigh frustration caused by input masks; but, that's conjecture on my part.

Comment: I highly respect LukeW usability research and here is a link showing the good way and bad way of masking.  Notice how the good way never changes what the user types in and the bad way does -- http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?756

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The term used for these format-constrained inputs is **masked inputs** or **mask input**.

Here is a demo which includes a broad range of masks (date, time, phone number, etc).  If you [Google 'masked input'](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=masked%20input) you will find plenty more examples.

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

And a screenshot for posterity in case the link dies in the future.

[image: screenshot]

It isn't a particularly descriptive term for lay users (e.g. your marketing team).  For that kind audience, I describe them as 'formatted inputs' or 'formatted number inputs', but then introduce the term 'masked input' so they know how to use it in the future.

Here's another common masked input, the Windows serial number widget:

[image: windows SN input]

For extra geek credit, the term is an evolution of an approach used in data entry in the early days of programming to ensure correct input.  See:

- [Wikipedia: Input Mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_mask)
- [What is an input mask?](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-an-input-mask.htm)

Comment: I never heard about the term _mask input_ before. First I wanted to go with _constrain input_ (which dev colleagues are using) but it suggests allowing any input before validation. The other term would be _strict input_ which prevent users from entering wrong input but sounds quite technical and misleading. Therefore, I'm going with your answer because it sounds and looks plausible to me!

Comment: @IsgerJanson lol.  I've added some references to the history of the term which may help you draw the connection

Comment: Quite obviously, a simple reversion of a technical term. (Should have known that!)

Comment: But the term masked input only refers to the processing of the input, and not the format or layout of the input field that reflects the way the user interface element looks like (as in the second image in the question).

Comment: Masked is used to refer to the format, not the processing. That is what the "mask" is nowadays. As noted above, the term has evolved from its mainframe days. The plug-ins exist not because processing is required (although in some cases like phone numbers, it is required because of different country formats), but because the lack of native html support means that jquery polyfills are necessary to ensure cross platform support.

Comment: @tohster but in the screen shots you provided the input field is still shown as a single input field rather than the input field reflecting what the format should look like. I am after something that will differentiate between the two styles when specifying how the input fields should be designed. Thanks.

Comment: Let's take credit card numbers as an example. One masked input may use a blank text box and format numbers into groups as you type. Another may use four boxes containing 4 numbers each which is more skeuemorphic with credit cards. They are both masked inputs but the mask format is different for the two widgets.

Comment: @tohster So how would you differentiate between the two different types of masked inputs? If I just said create a masked input and give a screenshot will it be enough, or do I need to call them different names so that it is clear how I want them implemented differently. That's pretty much the questions I am trying to ask, and that would be the answer I am after.

Comment: @MichaelLai got it. For pure formatted masked inputs (e.g. credit cards) I usually just pass the FE developers the widget wireframe and tell them that's the mask design I want to use.  There are some masked inputs that are more complicated....international phone numbers are an example where the mask format actually changes depending on the country-code used (e.g. +65 9385-2938 for Singapore, or (408) 293-5884 for US)...so in this case I lay out sample masks and sit down with the devs to make sure implementation is clear (e.g. using Google libphonenum)

Answer (score 4):

These are **units** or **formats** you are talking about. For example a date is a numeric format that consists of three units: years months and days. It will depend on the context which term to use actually.

Since the question got edited it is now clear that it is about inputs that guide users to a valid format. In that case **guided/guiding inputs** could be an option.

If thats not the appropriate term to use, how about **strict inputs**, since it is a strict format to follow. Or you might prefer to talk about a precise format and **precise inputs** but as I said, it all depends on the context.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts here. I would also suggest _Open Inputs_ (borrowing from the open source movement) vs _Preformatted Inputs_. I use the latter when communicating with my development teams. For me, _preformatted_ inputs refer to the mask solution we put in place [Mask JavaScript API](http://goo.gl/ZPsTm) which I received from [Luke W's post](http://goo.gl/yNzOvb).

Answer (score 4):

> **I am trying to come up with some common terms and definitions that are
>   suitable to use for specification or design documents**

I don’t think i can come-up with a better suggestion than  the one you mentioned "formatted' numeric input field" Its the best possible outcome and I don't think you should worry too much because its long, though you can make adjustments when this is included in documentation. For example:

> **Formatted Input Field (numeric) where numeric becomes an additional attribute!**

The most important thing is that its understandable and clear and given that it needs to go into documentation for an audience that might not be well versed in technical knowledge, the logic should be that descriptivness beats *conciseness*

If we look at this purely from labelling point of view then your suggestion is the least ambiguous and most descriptive of all alternatives I have seen so far and would be the most useful for a larger audience.

### Input Field vs Input Type or Input Element:

If you are to ask as many people in your target audience to define this element than I am sure that the majority will use “input field ” or “input box” its a hypothesis but could be easily tested:)

The term **“Input Field”** will work well as opposed to **"Input Type"** or **"Input Element"**  these being more ambiguous and could trigger further inquires when used in design documentation. Also the term "Input Field" focuses on a unique element with a descriptor "field" as opposed to using input or inputs only, which could be confused with other form controls.

### Formatted Input Fields:

The term **"formatted"** is both descriptive, unambiguous and its meaning is widely understood which will help convey how the input field works as opposed to “fixed” which is very restrictive and unfamiliar and could lead readers to question it further.

In addition,the term **"formatted"** denotes the act of arranging or put into a format regardless of how this is done which in my opinion describes: **What the field is rather than how it works.**

Answer (score 2):

You don't like the term type so how about structured or structured input.

Formatted is not a good as a date has many formats.

If I understand what you are asking why not just use what is called in HTML - type
Why not just go by the actual input type name and call them types
The tech name as in

```
<input type="text"
```

The type values/names are pretty clear even to non-developers
HTML5 added several new input types:

color
date
datetime
datetime-local
email
month
number
range
search
tel
time
url
week

The type is more than just a format. It can dictate a behavior.
This link covers it much better than I can [HTML5 input types](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/).
I know that link is techy and this is a UX site but behaviors are part of UX.

Your example of date, time, and telephone number as specific formats is not correct.  Date can be 1/31/2000 or 2000.01.31.  Time can be 2:15 PM or 14:15.

I don't know why you are arguing with a masked input as if you want to restrict to a specific input format that is exactly what a mask does.

To call date a "format" is an over simplification. Not all months have the same number of days.

Beyond a mask is validated input.  For example not all credit card numbers of 16 digits are valid.  There is checksum type validation.  Then there is a name matches the number validation.

- A type means one thing but can have multiple formats
  A type will determine equality of different formats
  1/31/2000 = 2000.01.31 (date)
  12.00 = 12.0 (decimal)
- A mask only accepts certain input
- A validation performs advanced processing beyond just static input rules
  (e.g. 16 digits)

Comment: I am looking for a generic term that would cover the range of numeric input types that require a specific rather than free text input fields.

Comment: But the types you reference are not a specific format. The HTML protocol calls them types for a reason. Date can be 1/1/2000 or 2000.01.31. Time can be 2:15 PM or 14:15.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric Input Pattern, as suggested terminology from HTML5:

http://html5pattern.com/

I see it as a Subset of a Numeric Input.